# Can I upload a map of a friend to a Minecraft Realm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

Currently we are playing multiplayer with normal "hosting" when he is online, but I have been thinking of buying a realms server. However I would need to upload his map to said server as we plan to continue playing on this world.

We are both on XBOX ONE but I do have access to a Windows 10 PC if that is needed.

Is it somehow possible to let him upload his map to my realms server?

Comment: You could possible get him to give you the map via keyfob/google drive etc. then upload it from your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked. And looked... And looked.

And it doesn't look like Minecraft actually supports this.

There are two possible ways you could do this:

The easy way) You get your friend to host the realm. I mean, you're both using it and it's not expensive.

The hard way) Get your friend to get Minecraft Realms trial. Have him upload the world. Get him to log in to a PC copy of bedrock and download a copy of the realm. It may take some jiggery pokery, but you *should* be able to use that local copy of the map using your account on the same PC. Now you have your own copy of the map, you can get your Realms account and upload it to your realm.

To be honest, I'd go with the former. I have a realm for me and my nephew and it costs me about £3 a month. Not the kind of money that people often end up fighting over.

Comment: Do the savegames not get synced across Xbox and PC via Xbox Live?

Comment: So, the maps you have normally are local. The ones on Realms are actually hosted elsewhere. So, it's not that the savegames are synced it's that your joining a game that Microsoft is hosting for you.

Comment: Ah no, what I meant is that my friend might be able to get on his PC and then search for the Map via Windows Explorer and send me the file

Comment: So I had hoped that Microsoft may sync the savegames because of Xbox Play Anywhere or something xD

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works but I typically use mobile and Xbox and none of my mobile worlds are on my Xbox and vice versa.

Comment: If you own a Realm you can upload to and download from it at will though, which is how you move them between platforms.